# Magento 2 Join with ProductRepositoryInterface

Tags: magento2, interface

I want to add join query with productRepository. Here is my class. Can anyone help with this.

I have used `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::getList()` method to get product list and now i want to add join with other table.

I am getting products data.

```
<?php

namespace Example\Product\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SortOrderBuilder;

/**
 * Class Productlist
 *
 * @package Example\Product\Model
 */
class Productlist implements \Example\Product\Api\ProductlistInterface
{


    /**
     * Product repository
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * SearchCriteria builder
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * SortOrder builder
     * @var SortOrderBuilder
     */
    private $sortOrderBuilder;

    /**
     * ListProduct constructor
     *
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        SortOrderBuilder $sortOrderBuilder
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->sortOrderBuilder = $sortOrderBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Get list of products
     *
     * @return ProductInterface[]
     */
    public function getProductList($params)
    {
        // Create the SearchCriteria
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

        // Load the products
        $products = $this->productRepository
            ->getList($searchCriteria)->setSearchCriteria();

        foreach ($products->getItems() as $product){
            echo $product->getName();
        }
        exit;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got solutions and I can able to make join using extension_attributes.xml

Created new file : `etc/extension_attributes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="parent_product_id" type="int">
            <join reference_table="catalog_product_bundle_selection" reference_field="product_id" join_on_field="entity_id">
                <field>parent_product_id</field>
            </join>
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Now when table will automatically add to `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface getList()`

Let me know if you have still any confusion for this.

Comment: hi dharmesh how we can use custom attributes value in reference_field